# Is there anyway to contact whoever handles commercial apps for the Software Center?

Tags: application-development, application-submission

I have some problems with the way my app is published due to a name change. Also, I want to inquire as to if/how my application can be made available for Oneric Ocelot, and when they come out future versions of Ubuntu.

I also wanted to know if there way a way to provide license keys to users who purchased before I added them. The keys are not used for DRM, but to allow users to download versions of my software for other Linux distributions, so it's kind of important that I provide them.

Is there anywhere I can ask this sort of thing? I sent a question asking if it's possible to release my application on Oneric Ocelot via the application feedback tab, however, it hasn't been answered in two updates.

EDIT: Still no luck... is there anyone who can provide some assistance?

Comment: Hi Razick what is the name of your application?

Comment: @DavidPitkin Swiftcrypt, formerly CryptWiz.

Comment: @DavidPitkin was there a reason you asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Application Review Board member can be contacted by clicking their name from the feedback screen, which will take you to a Launchpad page allowing you to sign in and view their email address (assuming they have provided it).

A member of the board has emailed me and been extremely helpful, more than he needed to be.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the contact form is your best bet. It normally takes some time to get a reply though as Canonical does not yet seem to have the capacity to answer such detailed questions quickly, but you should be able to get a response through the contact form eventually.

Comment: What contact form?

Comment: I think commercial devs (who pay for the dev program) may get some kind of priority support...?

Comment: Commercial developers don't pay except for the 20% commission on sales. I believe there is a way to get a support representative and extra help from Canonical through the partner program, however, I am not an Ubuntu Software Partner.

Comment: OK, I thought [this](https://launchpad.net/+tour/join-launchpad#commercial) and commercial apps were the same program but apparently not...I'd try IRC, a lot of the Canonical people hang out there and perhaps someone can help.

Comment: I never seem to get a reply via IRC, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [his answer to this question re commercial apps](https://askubuntu.com/a/170015/58612), you may want to contact [Michael Nelson](https://askubuntu.com/users/80252/michael-nelson) at Canonical via IRC on freenode (nick: *noodles775*).

Also, in general try joining channel `#ubuntu-app-devel` on freenode IRC and just asking, a lot of the Canonical people hang out there and someone may be able to help or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: I never seem to get a reply in #ubuntu-app-devel,I'll try Micheal.